# Getting this regex expression to work in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an html checkbox element with the following name:

```
type_config[selected_licenses][CC BY-NC-ND 3.0]
```

I would like to break this name apart as follows and returned as part of an array:

```
["type_config",  "[selected_licenses]", "[CC BY-NC-ND 3.0]", "[selected_licenses][CC BY-NC-ND 3.0]"]
```

I thought I could do this by using a regular expression in javascript. Here is the expression that I am using:

```
matches = /([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)((\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\s]*\])+)*/.exec(element_name);
```

but this is the result I am getting in my matches variable:

```
["type_config[selected_licenses]", "type_config", "[selected_licenses]", "[selected_licenses]", index: 0, input: "type_config[selected_licenses][CC BY-ND 3.0]"]
```

I am half way there. What am I doing wrong in my regular expression? I guess I should also ask if it is possible to accomplish what I want with a regex?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. You can use it even inside `[]`, like `[\w\.\s]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will make that change. However it doesn't resolve my question.

Comment: In fact, I've readied an answer for that. Check it out! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this kind of goal is that there's no simple way to achieve this with regular expression, i.e. a simple `match` call. In short, even if you put a quantifier after a capturing group, the captured string will always be just one.

You'll have to rely on something more specific, like breaking the string with a repeated use of `indexOf`, or something like

```
name.split(/(?=\[)/);
```

Maybe you want to be sure that `name` is formally correct.

Comment: Sorry, too quick to respond on my part :-). So it isn't possible - that is good to know. I will go with what you suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very ugly problem. I don't know how repeatable this is, but I can do it:

### Regex

`^(\w+)(?<firstbracket>\[(?<secondbracket>[^]]*)\]\[(.*?)\])$`

### Replacement

`["$1", "[$3]", "[$4]", "$2"]`

---

### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/eD9mH8